# How to detect when a live DigiScan image has finished acquiring a complete frame with an event handler?

Tags: dm-script

I am looking to take snapshots of a live DigiScan image.

However, I want to do so only when a complete (or nearly so) frame has been acquired!

Attaching an event handler to a live DigiScan image does not work, as the image 'changes' with each line acquired serially.

I am hoping to monitor just the last few pixels of the live image and only capture an image when those change. Is this possible?

Comment: I slightly reworded your question for readability, but well: I feel it is too broad, and doesn't fit the scope of this community. You should turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask, and improve this question to be in the scope of this community.

Comment: @GhostCat The question is clear enough in the context of the programming language (dm-script) because of its central application field (Electron Microscopy). Thanks for the edit, though.

Answer (score 1):

Your suggestion is exactly what I did:  Using the data_changed event as a trigger, and in the event handling method check the value of the last image pixel for if it has changed. (The initial value of the first pass is guaranteed to be zero. From then on, keep the value of a check.)

So, essentially you’ve answered your own question - what remains unclear?

You can check a single pixel using the `GetPixel()` command, or the `img[x,y]` notation.

---

**Example**

```
class CFrameCompleteListen
{
    number lastPixelValue
    number listenID
    number frameCount, sx, sy
    void OnDataChanged( object self, number flags, image img )
    {
        number value = img.GetPixel( sx-1,sy-1)
        if ( value == lastPixelValue )
            return 

        frameCount++
        lastPixelValue = value
        Result( "\n Image [" + img.GetLabel() + "] frame #"+ frameCount + " complete." )
        if ( 3 <= frameCount )
        {
            ImageRemoveEventListener( img, listenID )
            Result("\n Listening stopped." )
        }
    }

    object Launch( object self, image img )
    {
        lastPixelValue = 0
        frameCount = 0
        sx = img.ImageGetDimensionSize(0)
        sy = img.ImageGetDimensionSize(1)
        listenID = ImageAddEventListener( img, self, "data_changed:OnDataChanged" )
        Result("\n Listening started." )
        return self
    }
}

 Alloc( CFrameCompleteListen ).Launch( GetFrontImage() )
```

Comment: @GhostCat possibly so, although OP seems to know the hard bit (the event handling code) already. Will add some example when I am in front of some proper keyboard again later... (Typing on the phone)

Comment: Keep in mind: your answer is not only for the OP. It should work for *any* future reader coming by! This is a Q/A site, not a help forum ;-)

Comment: The solution @BmyGuest proposes works, but it lacks precision. A 512 x 512 (2s) live serial image triggers around 20 events per frame, or roughly one every 26 lines. This means that capturing the real end of the frame will be anywhere from on time to 26 lines late due to the listener's overhead. What I was aiming for was triggering a single exclusive event when the last pixel changed - hence my attempts to abstract that region as an image and append the listener to that image, rather than to the live image as a whole. Thanks again.

Comment: @DaveMitchell This makes no sense to me. The update event is always triggered when the image-memory is changed. A sub-section of the image will not show anything different. The fact, that the DigiScan image updates in "chunks" is due to the acquisition code writing a buffer "at once" and then triggering the update event only once after that write.

Comment: I can understand that Dave would like to minimize extraneous event traffic.  Following his idea, I have created a slight alteration of the example script that passes frontImage[sy - 1, sx - 1, sy, sx] to the Launch method.  But this does not work at all.  The listener does not even take effect and gets released immediately.  I don't understand why that is so.  Not sure how to post my version of the script in a comment.  Should I post it as a separate answer (even though it is actually a follow-on question)?

Comment: @MikeKundmann yes, please post it as new "alternative" answer.

Comment: @MikeKundmann However, I'm pretty sure your solution doesn't work becuase what you're sending on is just a slice to a subsection looking at the same memory location. That will not have it's own update event. And even if, it wouldn't improve anything, as the CPU would still need to check "that last pixel" only for every update of the big image to descided whether or not an event for the "subimage" needs to be created. So it would essentially doing the "GetPixel()" check "internally" instead of the script only.

Comment: The way image updates work are, that there are "locker" objects which essentially ensure that a memory location can not be written to by more than one process at a time. (While acive, it locks-out all other attempts. They will wait until the lock is cleared.) During such a lock, one value or many can be written. Once the lock is stopped, the code goes on to "inform" all registered listeners that an "update" happened. That's when the script event would also be called. There is no way of getting an event "during the lock". So in case of digiscan, you always get an event when the data is updated.

Comment: This happens in chunks. I'm pretty convinced, one such "chunk" is including the last pixel as the last value of it's "chunk" and hence you will get an update event *exactly* at the time of frame-complete. Hence, I'm not yet seeing Dave's issue. What *maybe* can happen is, that the script runs at a different thread and that it takes too much time doing stuff while the DigiScan is already (on a different thread) going on with writing new data to the beginning of the image. I have not noticed such in praxis, though. In any way, I would perform a "clone" immediately after the GetPixel-check.

Comment: Or in other words: One does get an "exact" end-of-frame event, but it is one of the many "update" events and one has to "filter it". If there would be a specific "end-of-frame" event (there is none), that would not change anything in the effects and issues, it would just perform this single (and fast) check one level deeper in the code. The point is, that the "image_data_update" event is fired when the memory changes and *not* on regular time-intervals. Hence it does not make sense to involve exposure or frame times in the thinking.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is merely to post the alternate strategy mentioned in the comments to the answer with the original example script.  Please note that the following altered version DOES NOT WORK since the attempt to register an image change listener seems to fail (the listener object is immediately released).

```
class CFrameCompleteListen2
{
    number lastPixelValue
    number listenID
    number frameCount
    
    void OnDataChanged( object self, number flags, image img )
    {
        Result("\n Change event." )

        number value = img.GetPixel( 0, 0 )
        if ( value == lastPixelValue )
            return 

        frameCount++
        lastPixelValue = value
        Result( "\n Image [" + img.GetLabel() + "] frame #"+ frameCount + " complete." )
        if ( 3 <= frameCount )
        {
            ImageRemoveEventListener( img, listenID )
            Result("\n Listening stopped." )
        }
    }

    object Launch( object self, image img )
    {
        lastPixelValue = img.GetPixel( 0, 0 )
        frameCount = 0
        listenID = ImageAddEventListener( img, self, "data_changed:OnDataChanged" )
        Result("\n Listening started." )
        return self
    }
    
    ~CFrameCompleteListen2( object self )
    {
        Result( "\n Listener released.\n" )
    }
}

void main()
{
    image targetImage := GetFrontImage()
    number targetW = targetImage.ImageGetDimensionSize(0)
    number targetH = targetImage.ImageGetDimensionSize(1)

    image lastPixelImage := targetImage[targetH - 1, targetW - 1, targetH, targetW]
    lastPixelImage.ShowImage()
    
    object listener = Alloc( CFrameCompleteListen2 ).Launch( lastPixelImage ) 
}

main()
```

---

#### Edit: *by BmyGuest* (see comments):

The following script shows, that displaying a "sliced" memory creates a new image with a new reference:

```
ClearResults()
image newFull := RealImage("Full",4,100,100)
Result("\n Image label 'full':" + newFull.ImageGetLabel() + " | ID:" + newFull.ImageGetID())
newFull.ShowImage()
Result("\n Image label 'full':" + newFull.ImageGetLabel() + " | ID:" + newFull.ImageGetID())
image getFull := GetFrontImage()
Result("\n Image label 'full' (front):" + getFull.ImageGetLabel() + " | ID:" + getFull.ImageGetID())

image slice := newFull[0,0,2,2]
Result("\n Image label 'slice':" + slice.ImageGetLabel() + " | ID:" + newFull.ImageGetID())
slice.ShowImage()
Result("\n Image label 'slice':" + slice.ImageGetLabel() + " | ID:" + newFull.ImageGetID())
image getSlice := GetFrontImage()
Result("\n Image label 'slice' (front):" + getSlice.ImageGetLabel() + " | ID:" + getSlice.ImageGetID())
```

The output of that script is something like:

[image]

Consequently, the listener script above fails and unregisters the listener because the 'lastPixelImage' does *not* reference the shown 1-pixel image and hence goes out of scope immediately (removing the listener in the process). The script *does* work, if one grabs the displayed image after showing it and using that one as reference. Accordingly, the script would also work if the sliced image variable would be held in scope.

Comment: I am not surprised that this isn't giving a solution but I am a surprised by what is going on exactly and about the auto-destruct of the listener. A bit of experimentation answered that question while it puzzles me with even more newquestions. Apparenetly, when a "slice" image is displayed, something odd goes on with images. The displayed image is has a *different* reference than the image used as the parameter, and the label of the referenced image changes!  I'm editing the question above to show what I mean.Anyway, the script above "works" with 'GetFrontImage()' after 'ShowImage()'

Comment: I guess it kind of makes sense that a "slice" reference (just a view on existing data) does not register as separate image (with own ID), or one could easily end up in situation where multiple views keep themselves in scope and prevent themselves from ever being released. The "ShowImage" command works around that issue by creating a separate object. All in all, the behavior is confusing though :c)

Comment: Indeed, doing as BmyGuest suggests does allow the example for CFrameCompleteListen2 to function correctly. Running it with this alteration does confirm that a data_changed event is triggered whenever ANY pixel of the full source image is accessed (no need even to change it).  So it is, indeed, always necessary to confirm whether the target (last) pixel has changed in order to be sure a complete frame has been captured.

Comment: The one remaining loophole with this approach is that no new frame is detected if the tested pixels of the image happen not to change from one frame to the next (relatively unlikely, except in cases of image intensity clipping at either the zero count level or saturation).