# Acquire a series of STEM images via the method of event listener

Tags: dm-script

Recently I am trying to attach an event listener to a live display so as to acquire a series of images automatically and the even map used is "data_value_changed". In TEM mode everything is fine and the 3D stack can be properly obtained. Unfortunately, while applying this to a live STEM image from the DigiScan, the script failed completely. Later on I just realized that in such a mode, the image is updated pixel by pixel with the scanning rather than frame by frame. Another event map "data_changed" was further tested but still ended up with failure.

With DM2.0 or later version, it seems to be much easier to acquire a series of customerized STEM images, since the DigiScan controlling can be conveniently accessable via scripting. Unfortunately, our microscope is quite old and only with DM 1.5 installed.

Is there any event map sepcific to this purpose or the approach of event handler is not suitable at all?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect when a live DigiScan image has finished acquiring a complete frame with an event handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52050885/how-to-detect-when-a-live-digiscan-image-has-finished-acquiring-a-complete-frame)  with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52057095/1302888). Please comment, if questions remain.

Comment: @BmyGuest: Thanks for the reminding. I am actually aware of the earlier discussion that you mentioned. I have tried my best to follow the idea there but still cannot fully understand the details, probably due to my inexperience in scripting. It would be very appreciated if some more plain explanations suitable to beginners can be provided.

Comment: OK, I will retract the close vote then. Did you test the script in the question's answer though? And can you maybe specify more closely where you have issues with it?

Comment: As an asside, I think your script idea is already implented on this homepage as ["StackBuilder"](http://digitalmicrograph-scripting.tavernmaker.de/HowToScript_index.htm). You want to contact the site-owner per email if you're only interested in the functionality. However, coding it yourself is surely more educational and 'fun' ;c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **The data changed event handler is suitable, but there is no event for a particular frame/complete event.**

Instead, your event-handling code needs to be creative and deal with the situation that you get more events than you want. You are really only interested in the event which (also) change the last pixel in an image (as the frame is sequentially filled), but you do get events whenever sub-parts of the image change.

So you need to "filter" those events out - as quickly and CPU-conservative as possible.

The easiest way is to gather the last pixel's *value* at each event and compare it to a stored value. If the value changed, then this pixel was changed, indicating the frame is "complete" and you want to use the event. Otherwise, just return without further action.

There is a very slim chance ( - for scanned images - ) that a "new" frame has the numerically *identical* value than the frame before, so this in most cases is all yoou need to do.

If this isn't enough for you, you may look at longer - but also more CPU cycles consuming - checks like each time computing a Boolean change map betwee "now" and "buffered" and keeping track of the "last" change. Then, if there is a "jump over" to an earlier index, you know that your "buffered" last image actually wa a full frame.
(Note, that you will *always* see the data update once at the end of frame. Hence this will work.)

There is an example of this type of script [in this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52057095/1302888). If this isn't working for you, please comment or rephrase your question for more details on where you run into issues.

Comment: Thanks for this useful answer. The example script can work properly in our online microscope, which accurately gives a count whenever the DigiScan image is "fully" updated. Now what is left is to integrate this bit of code into my script with the function that I need. Let me try it anyway. By the way, I really encountered the mentioned "slim chance" that the new frame with numerically identical value of the last pixel while testing on a simulated live STEM image. Perhaps add some random noise therein will help.

Comment: It seems that the StackBuilder has been installed in our DM (perhaps my colleagues alos have the same interest as me...) and it perfectly fits the need. However, I will still hope to code myself for accumulating some more experiences : )

Comment: @DMAdventurer Great! Let me know if you need further assitance. (And yes, a *simulator* can hold it's own issues ;c) )